# Pyrebase and Firebase Database Rules, how to deal with it with Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, pyrebase

I'm new in the world of Firebase and I'm using Pyrebase as library for Python 3.7. To test this library I've created a realtime database with public rules:

```
// These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app,
// read and write access to your database
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

It was easy to test the API. Now, I want to introduce more restrictive rules in my case are:

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user ID from the Firebase auth token
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm encountering a lot of problems and doubts. My Python Code for authentication is this:

```
        firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(self.config)
        self.username = email
        self.password = password
        self.db = firebase.database()
        self.auth = firebase.auth()
        # authenticate a user
        self.user = self.auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(self.username, self.password)
```

Now when I try to read something for example:

```
#user_id is the name  of the child of main_document 
db.child(self.main_document).child(user_id).get(self.user['idToken']).val()
```

My Db structure is this:
[image]

Reading from doc and trying to understand from rule syntax, I see that I need the UID of the user that I can obtain from `self.user` variable. But How can I "send" to Firebase in order to give it the possibility to make that match? I hope I was clearly :)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to sign a user in with Firebase Authentication, as shown in the Pyrebase documentation on [authentication](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#authentication): `firebase.auth().sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)`.

Once the user is signed in, their credentials will automatically be sent to Firebase with each request, and Firebase will make those available as `auth` in your database's security rules.